# separate an row of indexes by specific name

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

hey guys I'm new in pandas and I have a question:
I have a dataset and want to separate all the NYA rows from the rest
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eIT0A.png)

I tried "iloc" but didn't get the result I wanted